# Check if File or Module Has Been Imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, react-component

Is there a way to check whether or not a file or module has been imported.  I am creating a React Component -- and I want it to act one way if it is used on a page where a particular package has been imported and another way if not.

Just to be clear, by 'imported', I mean `import X from 'y'`

Is this possible?  If so, how can I do it?

**UPDATE**

The file I want to check for is the `Formik` React component from the Formik library.  That is to say, if he imported formik (`import { Formik } from 'formik'`) then I want to do one thing, if not, I want to do something else.  How do I check if a component has been imported?

Comment: Can't you just check `if x` - do something, `else` - do something else.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov I'm not sure how I do that check.  Please see my updated question to explain what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/):-

Example -

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import("react-dom")
.then(ReactDOM => ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Dynamic import</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
```

Here `import('react-dom')` returns `promise`, if that promise resolves then that package is available and you can use that module in the callback function.

Or you could also try- [Reference](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/526)

```
if(__webpack_modules__[require.resolveWeak("mod1")]) {
  // do something when mod1 is available
}
if(require.cache[require.resolveWeak("mod1")]) {
  // do something when mod1 was loaded before
}
```

Hope that helps!!!